# Interaction of IPSec and WinPE in MDT 2010 sequence

Tags: ipsec, windows-firewall, wds, mdt-2010

I'm in the process of enabling IPSec and Windows Advanced Firewall within my organization. 
We are also using MDT 2010 for OS deployment.

This is the first time I've tried a new sysprep and capture process and I'm getting timeouts.
More specificially “A connection to the distribution share could not be made”.

When I try to ping DEPLOYSERV it takes a long time for it to begin responding. My guess is that since the IP address isn't changing that the server is expecting the WinPE environment to be responding with IPSec which it can not do.

The server is in request inbound and outbound mode.

What can I do to correct this behavior without making any changes to the server side IPSec configuration (which needs to remain fixed for our other clients)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping the windows firewall service and giving it a few minutes for the IPSec connections to clear is a quick and easy workaround. Not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Windows PE supports the IPSec protocol by default, however it may require some configuration changes depending on the specific settings you have used. The TechNet article ‘[Configure IPSec Support for Windows PE Client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748956(v=ws.10).aspx)’ should help you to resolve your issue, hopefully without needing to change your setup.

Hope this helps